# Does an App rating (Android / iOS) change with country

Tags: rating, country

I wanted to know if given an app (Android / iOS) can the content rating of the app change with country? can the same app have different maturity ratings for two different countries?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not really about programming